# Javascript - Regular expression with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a complex regular expression pattern and a small part inside the regex is confusing me. Here is the example,

```
var s = /^((?!\bN\b).)*$/
console.log(s.test('N'));
```

While passing,

`N123` - `true` 
`NABC` - `true` 
`N` - `false` 
`N` - `false` (with space right next to N)
`N/` - `false` 
`N+` - `false` 
`N-` - `false`

**Question:** Strings works fine only when it has a continuous characters following with `N`. But why it is false when there is a space or special character?

Comment: What is input string?  What are you trying to match? What is expected result?

Comment: You didn't well understand what a word boundary is and how it is related to the `\w` character class. Read more about it.